# Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'MavenRepo' was added by build file 'build.gradle.kts'

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I want to add maven repository to kotlin project: https://jitpack.io/

I add the following code to build.gradle.kts

```kotlin
repositories {
     mavenCentral()
     maven {
         setUrl("https://jitpack.io/")
     }
}
```

But got the following error

```
Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'MavenRepo' was added by build file 'build.gradle.kts'

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

You can add the maven repository normally: https://jitpack.io/